# Export/Read Multiple Excel(xls) workbooks to one DataFrame

Tags: python, excel, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I need to export/read 3months of excel files into one DataFrame.
Files are named "EOD RATES 01.06.2022.xls" date changes with each excel file.
Need to capture the excels using pandas

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Question is unclear, what are files, what are sheets, what are data, what is expected ouput?

Comment: my_excel = pd.read_excel("c:\\folder\\file_name.xls")

Comment: Files are named EOD RATES 01.06.2022.xls each file the date and the end changes for the data captured to that particular date.

Comment: Example pic uploaded to the question.

Comment: output is to capture the rates in each excel and compile them to one excel file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need join all excel files use:

```
import glob


files = glob.glob('folder/*.xls')
df = pd.concat([pd.read_excel(f) for f in files], ignore_index=True)
print (df)
```

Comment: I have to replace 'folder/* with the files location?

Comment: @Dhakshika - Sure, it is necessary.